# Should noun tags be pluralized?

Tags: discussion, tags

Conventions are a good thing. It seems we're leading toward plural forms of all tag names that are nouns, as you can see from the [tag page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags).

I'd like to come to a concensus on the "proper" pluralization for noun tags so we can go through the list and make synonyms, so we don't have awkward situations where [lists](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lists) and [list](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list) are different tags.

So which form should we prefer?

Answer (score 1):

I think **noun tags should be pluralized**. Thinking about it, questions are about "a list", they're about "lists" so the plural form makes the most sense to me.

If it's an abstract concept [website-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design) or field of interest [hci](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hci) it's fine that it's not pluralized in my mind; think about it, you're not talking about interaction designs, you're talking about interaction design, the thing.